# Filter every n:th event

Tags: sensu

Is there any way of creating a filter that filters every n:th event where n is different for different checks. I.e I would like to specify a field in each check such that I can control the filter frequency for different checks.

I have some checks that run once a day, some checks that runs once an hour and some that runs every minute. Using the same filter where I filter every n:th occurrence would not work for the different checks.

Is there any way of avoiding creating 10 different filters with different frequency?

Edit: I also have to create 10 different handlers, each that uses a different filter. Not a very clean solution and very much duplicated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fine folks at Sensu have implemented what I asked for. It uses replacement tokens in the filter part as well now.

```
{
  "filters": {
    "occurrences": {
      "negate": true,
      "attributes": {
        "occurrences": "eval: value > :::check.occurrences|60:::"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [Mutators](https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/mutators) ? I really haven't tried them, but according to the description they could help you to manipulate the output of the check before they reach to the handler.
In theory you could manipulate the output to "normalize".

I am afraid is not possible to achieve what you tried with only filters.

Comment: Unfortunately the mutator is run after the filter. I have made a issue at Sensu's git about the order of mutator and filter and we will see.